# Null variables are not generated properly

Tags: php, soap

PHP 5.6.30 on Apache 2.2.32

I am trying to make a call with SoapClient. One of the classes in the structure of the request has a lot of attributes and most of them must be sent as `xsi:nil="true"`. Here is a simpler class for an example

```
class myClass {
  public $attribute1;
  public $attribute2;
  public $attribute3;
}
```

When I send the request the XML without assigning anything (or null to all attributes) is generated as follow (skipping the soap-env and such):

```
<ns1:class>
  <ns1:attribute1 xsi:nil="true">
    <ns1:attribute2 xsi:nil="true">
      <ns1:attribute3 xsi:nil="true"></ns1:attribute3>
    </ns1:attribute2>
  </ns1:attribute1>
</ns1:class>
```

What I expect is

```
<ns1:class>
  <ns1:attribute1 xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns1:attribute2 xsi:nil="true" />
  <ns1:attribute3 xsi:nil="true" />
</ns1:class>
```

If I assign a value to lets say attribute2 then the XML will be generated this way:

```
<ns1:class>
  <ns1:attribute1 xsi:nil="true">
    <ns1:attribute2>my_value</ns1:attribute2>
    <ns1:attribute3 xsi:nil="true"></ns1:attribute3>
  </ns1:attribute1>
</ns1:class>
```

Obviously the remote server is not accepting my request!

Any thoughts on this problem?

BTW I am not providing the WSDL as I would first have to ask for permission.

Thank you

Comment: You need to show your code. Can you make a version of the WSDL with all the proprietary names replaced?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was a non-issue, at one point while catching my response it was interpreted by the browser (tried Safari and FireFox) which was, I don't know why, producing the wrong display. Using the raw data (ie by writing it to a log file or something similar) got me the right output without this weird behaviour.